# SceneKit – How to edit 3d model

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

In Scenekit what I want to do is edit 3d model (or scene).

- 1. Let's say that I have a scene containing a table.
- 2. I know the transforms of table legs.
- 3. I want to crop only legs.
- 4. I can get array of vertices of table.
- 5. I filter the array whether each one's position only for leg position.
- 6. Then I get the vertices forming legs.

My questions is, how can I make a new 3d model with this vertices.

Is there any way make this happen easily without put the index of vertices, let them connected on each adjacent vetex?

Answer (score 1):

At first I should say that SceneKit isn't a 3D editing tool like 3dsMax or Maya. It's a framework that allows you load models, play animations, create particle systems, simulate physics, generate shadows and render shaders.

However, Xcode ecosystem contains `Model I/O` framework performing `Constructive Solid Geometry Operations`, such as **`union`**, **`intersection`** and **`difference`**. Difference op is the one you're looking for. For this you need to use [MDLVoxelArray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlvoxelarray) class having `difference(with:)` instance method.

```swift
func difference(with voxels: MDLVoxelArray)
```

So, if you want to crop table's legs go this way.